# C#: Improving edge point extraction algorithm

Tags: c#, feature-extraction, image-recognition

I am working on an edge points extraction algorithm.
I have a List of points representing a blob (a group of connected pixels) and I want to extract edge points.
I have an example algorithm below, but I am wondering if there is a faster way.
I am using class for BlobPoint, because there is more to it than shown in the example below.
BlobPoint index value represent index value in the original image (image is 1D array of pixels, hence required width information).
This algorithm is build on idea that if a pixel on right or bottom or left or top does not exist in the list, then this point is an edge point.
The list will usually contain between 20 000 to 1 000 000 elements.
yr and yl are added for clarity.

[image: Example edge points]

```
public static List<BlobPoint> GetEdgePoints(this List<BlobPoint> points, int width)
        {
            int length = points.Count;
            List<BlobPoint> temp = new List<BlobPoint>();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                BlobPoint point = points[i];
                int x = point.X;
                int y = point.Y;

                int xr = x + 1;
                int yr = y;

                int xb = x - width;
                int yb = y - 1;

                int xl = x - 1;
                int yl = y;

                int xt = x + width;
                int yt = y + 1;

                if (!points.Any(p => p.X == xb && p.Y == yb) || !points.Any(p => p.X == xl && p.Y == yl) || !points.Any(p => p.X == xr && p.Y == yr) || !points.Any(p => p.X == xt && p.Y == yt))
                {
                    temp.Add(point);
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }

public class BlobPoint
{
    public int X = 0;
    public int Y = 0;
    public int Index = 0;
    public BlobPoint(int x, int y, int index)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

**My solution:**
Ok, I have done some testing and the method above is way too slow for my needs.
I will leave question as this might be of use to someone who looks for faster iteration method.
This is a solution I came up with, but it is still a bit slow:

```
public static Dictionary<int, List<BlobPoint>> GetEdgePoints(BlobPoint[] points, int[] labels, int image_width, int image_height)
        {
            int length = labels.Length;
            if (image_height * image_width != length) throw new ArgumentException("image_width x image_height does not match labels.Length");
            if (length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("label array cannot be empty!");
            if (points.Length != length) throw new ArgumentException("points array length cannot be different from labels array length!");

            var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<BlobPoint>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int label = labels[i];
                if (label <= 0) continue;

                BlobPoint point = points[i];

                int x = point.X;
                int y = point.Y;

                int width_offset = image_width - 1;
                int height_offset = image_height - 1;

                if (x > 0 && x < width_offset && y > 0 && y < height_offset)
                {
                    if (labels[i + 1] == label && labels[i - 1] == label && labels[i + image_width] == label && labels[i - image_width] == label)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                } 

                if (dict.ContainsKey(label))
                    dict[label].Add(point);
                else
                    dict.Add(label, new List<BlobPoint>() { point });
            }

            return dict;

        }
```

Comment: Do you need to operate on the pixel list? Using the image directly would be much more performant because this would let you query points directly. What is the purpose of the `+ width` and `- width` in the coordinates?

Comment: Unless you change your data structure, I don't see much of what you can do to iterate through the list, since, well, lists are for iterating. You could hash the points based on coordinates on the first run, and then check contains on a second run. That would perhaps cut down about half of the calculations?

Comment: Nico Schertler +/- width are points above and below current point.

Comment: EricChen1248 - so, you think this is fastest way to iterate through it. My algorithm for blob detection first creates a int[] that contains labels corresponding to a blob. From this int[] I extract a List of BlobPoints, so I suppose working on int[] itself would be faster, but first I would have to Array.Copy it, in order to avoid modification. Both methods have some drawbacks. I was just wondering if there is a faster way to iterate through a list above.

Comment: Ok, I have just tested other variant where I use int[] labels, the method above is way to slow for my purpose, it is so slow that it basically froze Unity. Where int[] did it in 600 ms. I will leave question as this is still valid for someone who look for iteration speed question. I will add int[] result below, which is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use a two-dimensional Boolean array representing the image for this, in which the indices for the points you have are set to `true`. In exchange for some memory, and a single loop over the points in advance, this allows lightning-fast checks of whether a point is inside the list, removing *all* internal iterations for lookups on the points list. There is not a single `.Contains` or `.Any` or `.All` performed here. Just two loops over the main list, and eight very simple checks inside the second loop.

```
public static List<BlobPoint> GetEdgePoints(this List<BlobPoint> points, Int32 imageWidth, Int32 imageHeight)
{
    Boolean[,] pointInList = new Boolean[imageHeight, imageWidth];
    foreach (BlobPoint p in points)
        pointInList[p.Y, p.X] = true;
    List<BlobPoint> edgePoints = new List<BlobPoint>();
    Int32 lastX = imageWidth - 1;
    Int32 lastY = imageHeight - 1;
    foreach (BlobPoint p in points)
    {
        Int32 x = p.X;
        Int32 y = p.Y;
        // Image edge is obviously a blob edge too.
        // Coordinates checks are completely safe after the edge checks.
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == lastX || y == lastY
            || !pointInList[y - 1, x]
            || !pointInList[y, x - 1]
            || !pointInList[y, x + 1]
            || !pointInList[y + 1, x])
            edgePoints.Add(p);
    }
    return edgePoints;
}
```

This technically works without the image width and height, but then you need to do another loop in advance to get the maximum x and y present in your points, so you can make a `Boolean[,]` array that can contain all coordinates. If you *have* that image data, though, it's obviously a lot more efficient to just use it.

Not sure why you bother with the `BlobPoint` class over the standard `Point` struct, though. The index in the original array is just `p.Y * stride + p.X` anyway.

Comment: It is very nice idea. I will check it out. I am using BlobPoint as it contains some additional functionality. Furthermore, it gave me speed boost as I do not have to create/destroy struct but rather reuse existing object. For single image struct is faster, but for video stream class is faster. It comes down to this additional functionality. If it was just for storing x,y coordinates I would not bother with BlobPoint.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that makes sense. As for the `Boolean[,]` array, in most cases where I build up such a blob with my own functions I keep that Boolean array alongside my blob from the start, so I don't even have to build it up when doing an edge check like this. There _is_ one extra operation involved which is not really mentioned, and that's the actual initializing of the array, which in .Net (thankfully) means it's auto-cleared to its default value. Obviously that will also take _some_ time, though it shouldn't be much in the scope of the whole operation.

Comment: "I keep that Boolean array alongside my blob from the start" - This is what I do with Int[] used for labeling. Instead of destroying/instantiating it every time I just clear it. That is why I think that your method will work very nicely. I can update bool[] along int[] and it will save time on initial part of the algorithm. All image recognition algorithms are only viable for stream when texture size is not too big, hence memory req. for additional array will be minimal; using one more array would not hurt. So it will be loss in memory eff. but gain is speed.